# Vagrant box doesn't support provider parallels (need to use parallels not virtualbox with m1 chip)

Tags: macos, vagrant, parallels

How can i replace this vagrant box with one that supports parallels as a provider? I require parallels as virtualbox does not work on m1 macs.

I already followed these instructions for installing parallels plugin for vagrant
https://kb.parallels.com/en/122843

```
Bringing machine 'forge_offers_core' up with 'parallels' provider...
==> forge_offers_core: Box 'damianlewis/lamp-php7.1' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    forge_offers_core: Box Provider: parallels
    forge_offers_core: Box Version: >= 0
==> forge_offers_core: Loading metadata for box 'damianlewis/lamp-php7.1'
    forge_offers_core: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/damianlewis/lamp-php7.1
The box you're attempting to add doesn't support the provider
you requested. Please find an alternate box or use an alternate
provider. Double-check your requested provider to verify you didn't
simply misspell it.

If you're adding a box from HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, make sure the box is
released.

Name: damianlewis/lamp-php7.1
Address: https://vagrantcloud.com/damianlewis/lamp-php7.1
Requested provider: [:parallels]
```

the code in Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "damianlewis/lamp-php7.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to search a VM for the provider you'll use (in your case Parallels)
https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?order=desc&page=0&provider=parallels&sort=created

If you don't find one that matchs what you need, you'd need to go the path to build one yourself (using packer for example)